# Default authentication of QuickStart java project to use jwt

Tags: java, jwt, docusignapi

Being a newbie in DocuSign. I have downloaded the quickstart java project. I am able to authenticate using jwt by specifying http://localhost:8080/login&type=jwt first. This way jwt authentication works fine.

However, when I access http://localhost:8080/eg001 and I am redirected to authenticate using acg instead. Is there any way to default quickstart java project to use jwt as default autehntication?

Comment: Change it as the following will reverse the order of the default authentication to JWT.
   private String getLoginPath(AuthType authTypeSelected) {

        
      OAuthProperties oAuth2SsoProperties = jwtGrantSso; 
      if (authTypeSelected.equals(AuthType.AGC)) 
      { 
       oAuth2SsoProperties =  authCodeGrantSso;
   }
   
     
        //Added context path
        return config.getContextPath()+oAuth2SsoProperties.getLoginPath();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Find your **application.json** file (under the Resources folder) and find the "quickstart" value and change it from true to false.

Quickstart defaults to Auth Code Grant and will not let you choose JWT (unless as you found out you use the URL parameter).

The launchers can run in Quickstart mode or not in Quickstart mode where you get a drop-down menu to choose your auth type.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to modify the code to use jwt as default authentication mode? I did not find how to modify the code to take jwt as default value. Our goal is to use jwt as integration method.

Comment: to do that modify this code return new ModelAndView(getRedirectView(AuthType.JWT));
in https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/core/controller/IndexController.java#L49

Comment: specifically you need to change session.getAuthTypeSelected() to AuthType.JWT This consistently fires JWT authentication instead of ACG through the quickstart mechanism